# How to get exact y-coordinate from getLocation in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, getlocation

**Pre-req:**

Selenium 3.141

Firefox browser

**Requirement**: Get x,y co-ordinates of an webelement and perform mouse move to xy co-ordinates.
X is calculated properly whereas **y co-ordinate is falling 100 pixel short.**

**Note**: Webelement Formfield is hidden, user will perform vertical scroll and click on it. Co-ordinates are taken after scrolling.

```
WebElement fromfield = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-field-name,'deliverables')]"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",fromfield); //scroll to the webelement, a small wait is given after scrolling

org.openqa.selenium.Point fromLocation = fromfield.getLocation();

int fromfield_x = fromLocation.x; 
int fromfield_y = fromLocation.y; //getx/gety returns same values

Actual Output: x = 550, y = 600
Expected Output: x = 550, y = 700. (**Note**: If I pass 700, then mouse moves correctly to required element, but here y is calculated incorrect)
```

Other trials:Tried with browser open in fullscreen mode but the same issue.

Queries:

How to get exact y co-ordinate?

Is xy co-ordinate calculated from left top corner of desktop window or viewport?

---

### Update

**Status:**

Based on your suggestion, I tried below line of code and yes, it automatically scrolls to the required element.

```
WebElement source = fromfield.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@title,'test')]"));
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(source))).build().perform();
```

**Outcome 1:**

```
System.out.println("Y coordinate is: "+source.getLocation().getY());
int from_x = source.getLocation().getX();
int from_y = source.getLocation().getY();
```

I get y co-ords as 700 but the element might be at 900 pixels.

When I do mousemove, it moves to 700 pixels as returned, which is not the element to be dragged. My webelement (source) is still at 900 pixels. X co-ord is completely OK.

```
robot.mouseMove(from_x , from_y); //moves to 700 pixels
Actions maction=new Actions(driver);
Action drag = maction.clickAndHold(source).pause(3000).build();
drag.perform(); //tries to drag from 700 pixels
```

or

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(source))).clickAndHold(source).build().perform();
```

Again y is falling short. What would be the reason?

**Outcome 2:**
Above code snippet (movetoelement) works for chrome but not firefox.

Comment: What is happenning when you click those "wrong" coordinates? Nothing or some exception is thrown?

Comment: @AlexeyR.No exception. Mouse performs click at wrong co-ordinates and continues with next testcase.

Answer (score 3):

### getLocation()

[`getLocation()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation--) returns the point where on the page is the **top left-hand corner** of the rendered element is located i.e. a point, containing the location of the top left-hand corner of the element.

---

As an example to extract the *X* and *Y* coordinates of the *search box* on [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")));
  Point elementLocation = element.getLocation();
  System.out.println("X coordinate of the element is: "+elementLocation.getX());
  System.out.println("Y coordinate of the element : "+elementLocation.getY());
  //or
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")));
  System.out.println("X coordinate is: "+elem.getLocation().getX());
  System.out.println("Y coordinate is: "+elem.getLocation().getY());
  driver.quit();
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  X coordinate of the element is: 439
  Y coordinate of the element : 322
  X coordinate is: 439
  Y coordinate is: 322
  ```

---

### Update 1

It is not that clear from your question why you want to perform mouse move to `xy` co-ordinates. However for optimum results you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` before you attempt to invoke `scrollIntoView()`

  - As an example:

    ```
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("element"))));
    ```
  - You can find a relevant discussion in [How to scroll UP to an element and click in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886380/how-to-scroll-up-to-an-element-and-click-in-selenium/57886960#57886960)
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` before you attempt to interact i.e. invoke `click()`

  - As an example:

    ```
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ParentElement)))).perform();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(subElement))).click();
    ```
  - You can find a relevant discussion in [How to mouse hover a parent element and subsequently click on child element using Selenium and Action class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384816/how-to-mouse-hover-a-parent-element-and-subsequently-click-on-child-element-usin/52386828#52386828)

---

### Conclusion

As you mentioned *...perform vertical scroll and click on it...*, the `scrollIntoView()` looks as a pure **overhead** as:

the following methods:

- [moveToElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [elementToBeClickable()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

will automatically **scroll** the element within the *Viewport*.

---

### Update 2

As per your comment to address the error regarding *...out of bounds of viewport...* you can refer the discussion [org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (x, y) is out of bounds while MouseHover with GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413422/org-openqa-selenium-interactions-movetargetoutofboundsexception-x-y-is-out-o/55416099#55416099)

---

### Update 3

As per your comment *...it moves to 700 pixels as returned, which is not the element to be dragged...* it is worth mentioning that as I already mentioned within my answer that **`getLocation()`** returns the point where on the page is the **top left-hand corner** of the rendered element. Where as to perform a successful **Drag and Drop** operation, presumably the draggable element needs to be dragged up to certain percentage within the droppable element.

Additionally, if the html5 element to be dragged have the attribute **`draggable`** it needs to be handled differently which is a different topic altogether and we can discuss it in a seperate thread.

The relevant HTML would have helped us to a huge extent.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to scroll a webpage using selenium webdriver in Python without using javascript method execute_script()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361795/how-to-scroll-a-webpage-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python-without-using-javascr/55587059#55587059)
- [Selenium python Error: element could not be scrolled into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085152/selenium-python-error-element-could-not-be-scrolled-into-view/56361554#56361554)

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to get the x and y co-ordinated but the y co-ordinates is incorrect. It is 100pixel short. How to get exact y co-ordinate?

Comment: @sridattas Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB.Thanks again.I tried replacing scrollintoview with movetoelement and elementtobeclickable as suggested and I get exception:(517, 853.25) is out of bounds of viewport width(1898)and height(829),no scroll happens.Usecase is to perform dragdrop of element and the element is hidden, hence I need to scroll. I tried all other actions of dragdrop but didn't work since its an html5 dragdrop. I also tried solution provided by rcorreia. Now I'm trying with mousemove/press/release which works with hardcoded xy coordinates.but,i try to pass co-ords dynamically, x is OK but y is falling short.

Comment: **html5 dragdrop** is the key consideration here which you may like to ask as a separate question as that would be different story altogether.

Comment: @sridattas Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Updated my status and outcome. y seem to be still falling short. Scroll is now working with movetoelement. Can you please let me know why y coords is incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: @sridattas Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Perfect Solution +1